# Soft Question: Retaking Undergrad Courses vs Masters

Tags: soft-question, education

Hopefully the title explains my question.

I want to apply to PhD programs next fall (2021). My grades in algebra and number theory were rather poor (C+ and B- respectively). Analysis was descent (B). Overall, however, my record is not stellar by any means (2.9-3.0).

However, since graduating, I've been working thru the content of those courses in my own time, and a sense of maturity in proof-writing is solidifying. I have 2 options: retake undergrad some undergrad courses (ex. algebra, number theory, maybe even analysis) for A's or take the corresponding courses in a masters program at my local state uni (not extremely highly ranked or anything. decent school).

I will have the opportunity to do research in my masters program, in addition to opportunities to build strong connections with professors. I'm personally thinking a year of research with strong letters will hopefully put some bandage over a mediocre undergrad.

Some input from more experienced/knowledgeable folks would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Would this be on-topic for Academia SE?

Comment: I recently graduated with my B.S. in Mathematics with a concentration in differential geometry. I too am actually taking a similar route as you- as well, asking the same questions. My consensus is that in the mean time before applying for a PhD: get certified in a few programming languages (e.g. python, C, Java...) to up my resume, decide on a few courses to self study, and of course decide on a topic to eventually pursue in graduate school.

Comment: @MathDoctorR: cool! And yea that's exactly what I'm going for. Aiming to get at least a few months of SD work in so I don't exit my degree with no work experience.

Comment: @sai-kartik: I didn't know about the existence of that community. I'll post there. Thank you!

Comment: That sounds like a good direction. The reason for my comment above also was not to gloat, but to give reassurance that your questions about your future are completely normal and are being asked by recent grads as well!

Comment: @MathDoctorR: Great to hear. I hope then that we get some good responses on this post, and students like us and use it as a resource. Wishing you all the best!

Comment: The people who are in the best position to answer your question are the people on the math faculty at your institution, not random strangers on the internet.

Comment: @Adib0y360 You're welcome! :)